# Python Regex Sort and Print into a New Document with line breaks

Tags: python, regex, export

I am using the following code:

```
from__future__import print_function
import re
NDoc = raw_input("Enter name of new document ")+".txt"
log = open(NDoc, 'a')
file = raw_input("Enter a file to be sorted ")
xfile = open(file+".txt")

for line in xfile:
    l=line.strip()
    n=re.sub("(\B)(?=((MTH|ENG|SCN|HST)[|]))","\n",line)

if len(n) > 0:
    nl=split.("\n")
    for item in nl:
        log.write(item)
```

With this code I am trying to allow the user to create a name for a new document and then have the code create a document with that name and print the sorted information into it. Currently, I can create a new document and write into it, however, the data is just in one continuous string instead of having the line-breaks (\n) I want in it. When I print to the command prompt, it comes in separate lines, however, when I print to the `.txt` file, it is not.

**Edit:**

A sample line would be something like this:

```
MTH|lkdhskghgsh|aljfHST|alkjdfakljdfSCN|klahdfkj@$fadfklj|afENG|alkfd
```

And I would like it to look like this in the new document:

```
MTH|lkdhskghgsh|aljf

HST|alkjdfakljdf

SCN|klahdfkj@$fadfklj|af

ENG|alkfd
```

However, when I write it to a notepad document, it is still in the form of the sample line. When I `print(item)`, in the command prompt, it shows up as being on different lines (which is what I want for the notepad `.txt`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append a new line character to log.write(item).

```
for line in xfile:
    l=line.strip()
    n=re.sub("(\B)(?=((MTH|ENG|SCN|HST)[|]))","\n",line)

    if len(n) > 0:
        nl=split.("\n")
        for item in nl:
            log.write(item+'\n')
```

I tested your regex and it places the '\n' in the right place, so you can still keep your loop and your if statement and just add a newline char.

```
Input: MTH|lkdhskghgsh|aljfHST|alkjdfakljdfSCN|klahdfkj@$fadfklj|afENG|alkfd

Output (in a test.txt file I made):

MTH|lkdhskghgsh|aljf
HST|alkjdfakljdf
SCN|klahdfkj@$fadfklj|af
ENG|alkfd
```

Make sure your if statement is indented within the for loop and not outside. I'm guessing that was just a formatting issue in your question.